# php - how to fix an undefined variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just want to find some answer on my problem the error said that the query is undefined variable but i already put all the column needed to my table.    [here is the html file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PgKi.png)

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../CORE/dbconfig.php");

if(isset($_GET['book']))
{
    $start_date   = $_GET["start_date"];
    $end_date   = $_GET["end_date"];
    $vehicle_id = $_GET["vehicle_id"];

 if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
 $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];

 if(isset($_GET['vehicle_id'])){
 $vehicle_id = $_GET['vehicle_id'];
 $rate = $_GET['rate'];

 $start_date->format('Y-m-d');
 $end_date->format('Y-m-d');

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO booking (start_date, end_date, rental_amount, vehicle_id, customer_id)
    VALUES ('".$start_date."', '".$end_date."', '".$rate."', '".$vehicle_id."', '".$customer_id."')")
    or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connect));
}
}
}
if($query){
    echo'<script>
    alert("Record Updated!");
    window.location.href="homebooking.php";
    </script>';
}    
else{
    echo'<script>
    alert("Cannot Be Book!");
    window.location.href="homebooking.php";
    </script>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Please write the full error statement

Comment: Could you give the exact error?

Comment: Please format your code. `$query` is undefined if `$_GET['book']` is not set.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\wamp\www\HTML Design\home\book.php on line 27

Comment: You're only defining `$query` if `book` is set in the GET query string. Redo your logic....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `$_GET['book']` isn't set, causing $query not to get initialized and resulting in an error at `if($query){`. Use `if(isset($query)){`.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\wamp\www\HTML Design\home\book.php on line 27

Comment: ill try that but that happen

Comment: what about `if (!is_null($query)){...`

Answer (score 0):

```
  if( isset($_GET['customer_id']) && isset($_GET['vehicle_id']) && isset($_GET['rate']) ){
          $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
          $vehicle_id = $_GET['vehicle_id'];
          $rate = $_GET['rate'];
          $start_date->format('Y-m-d');
          $end_date->format('Y-m-d');

       $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO booking (start_date, end_date, rental_amount, vehicle_id, customer_id)
VALUES ('".$start_date."', '".$end_date."', '".$rate."', '".$vehicle_id."', '".$customer_id."')")
or die ("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($connect));

       if($query){
                     echo'
                         <script>
                           alert("Record Updated!");
                           window.location.href="homebooking.php";
                        </script>
                         ';
        }else{
                 echo'
                       <script>
                        alert("Cannot Be Book!");
                        window.location.href="homebooking.php";
                       </script>
                     ';

        }


  }
```

try this way of check vars .
i didn't change any thing in the code i just change the way of check on the variables i use this way to be sure the vars what i need already defined and found the values of it

Comment: i didn't change any thing in the code 
i just change the way of check on the variables 
i use this way to be sure the vars what i need already defined and found the values of it

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid your error notice:

```
include_once("../CORE/dbconfig.php");
$query = false; // this is the default set value, 
// which is then only updated if GET books is set, below:
if(isset($_GET['book']))
{
   ...
```

---

All of these `$_GET` values, you should perhaps look into using forms and POST values instead, as well as using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to minimise risk.

As well as this you should look at using [`urlencode`/`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your GET variables, too.